# How to Prove : $\frac{2}{(n+2)!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^{n+2}=\frac{n(3n+1)}{12}$

Tags: calculus, integration, combinatorics, analysis

While I calculate an integral 
$$
\int\limits_{[0,1]^n}\cdots\int(x_1+\cdots+x_n)^2\mathrm dx_1\cdots\mathrm dx_n
$$
I used two different methods and got two answers. I am sure it's equivalent, but how can I prove it?
$$\displaystyle\dfrac{2}{(n+2)!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^{n+2}=\dfrac{n(3n+1)}{12}$$
Sincerely thanks!

Comment: Curious about how to work out the $LHS$ .

Comment: By the way, it is surprising that you get this complicated term while calculating that simple integral.

Comment: @SangchulLee I just...just guess it, and  verify the equality via mathematica.

Comment: That is amazing! I knew that the sum has some nice expression, but have never known that it is given with such a simple look. Oh, and also (+1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fix $n$ and define $f(x)$ by

$$ f(x) = (1 - e^{-x})^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k e^{-kx}. $$

Then the left-hand side is equal to

$$ \frac{2}{(n+2)!} f^{(n+2)}(0). $$

So it suffices to find the Taylor polynomial of degree $n+2$ for $f(x)$ at $x = 0$. This can be done as follows:

\begin{align*}
f(x)
&= x^n \left( \frac{1 - e^{-x}}{x} \right)^n \\
&= x^n \exp\left[ n \log\left( \frac{1 - e^{-x}}{x} \right)\right] \\
&= x^n \exp\left( -\frac{n}{2} x + \frac{n}{24} x^2 + \cdots \right) \\
&= x^n \left( 1 - \frac{n}{2} x + \frac{(3n+1)n}{24} x^2 + \cdots \right) \\
&= x^n - \frac{n}{2} x^{n+1} + \frac{(3n+1)n}{24} x^{n+2} + \cdots.
\end{align*}

Therefore we have

$$ \frac{2}{(n+2)!} f^{(n+2)}(0) = \frac{2}{(n+2)!} \cdot \frac{(3n+1)n}{24} (n+2)! = \frac{(3n+1)n}{12}. $$

Answer (score 7):

Here’s a fairly straightforward combinatorial argument. Rewrite the equation as

$$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}(n-k)^{n+2}=\frac{n(3n+1)(n+2)!}{24}\;.\tag{1}$$

The lefthand side of $(1)$ is an [inclusion-exclusion calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) of the number of surjections from $[n+2]$ to $[n]$ (where as usual $[m]=\{1,\ldots,m\}$ for each $m\in\Bbb Z^+$). We now count these surjections in a different way.

If $f:[n+2]\to[n]$ is a surjection, either there is a $k\in[n]$ such that $|f^{-1}[\{k\}]|=3$, or there are distinct $k,\ell\in[n]$ such that $|f^{-1}[\{k\}]|=|f^{-1}[\{\ell\}]|=2$; call these surjections Type $1$ and Type $2$, respectively.

To construct a Type $1$ surjection we first choose $k$ in $n$ ways, then choose $f^{-1}[\{k\}]$ in $\binom{n+2}3$ ways, and then define $f$ on $[n+2]\setminus f^{-1}[\{k\}]$ in $(n-1)!$ ways, for a total of

$$n(n-1)!\binom{n+2}3=\frac{n(n+2)!}{3!}$$

Type $1$ surjections.

To construct a Type $2$ surjection we first choose $k$ and $\ell$ in $\binom{n}2$ ways, then choose the preimage of the smaller of $k$ and $\ell$ in $\binom{n+2}2$ ways, then choose the preimage of the larger of $k$ and $\ell$ in $\binom{n}2$ ways, and finally define the rest of $f$ in $(n-2)!$ ways, for a total of

$$\binom{n}2^2\binom{n+2}2(n-2)!=\frac{n(n-1)(n+2)!}8$$

Type $2$ surjections.

The total number of surjections is therefore

$$\frac{n(n+2)!}6+\frac{n(n-1)(n+2)!}8=\frac{n(3n+1)(n+2)!}{24}\;,$$

as desired.

Comment: (+1), Thanks for contributing to the remarkable diversity on this page. Interesting to observe that your types of surjections correspond precisely to the two types of coefficients from the integral I presented.

Comment: @Marko: My pleasure; it's good to have some variety, I think. I suspect that the correspondence is no accident, but I don't understand the relevant complex analysis well enough to see just what the connection is.

Comment: The connection can be seen by inspection, namely that the integral is equal to $$n!\times {n+2\brace n}$$ and the sets in these set partitions are precisely the pre-images of the $n$ possible slots in your surjections.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose we  seek to evaluate
$$\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} (n-k)^{n+2}.$$

We introduce
$$(n-k)^{n+2} =
\frac{(n+2)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+3}} \exp((n-k)z) \; dz.$$

This yields for the sum
$$\frac{(n+2)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+3}} \exp(nz)
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k {n\choose k} \exp(-kz) \; dz
\\ = \frac{(n+2)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+3}} \exp(nz)
(1-\exp(-z))^n \; dz
\\ = \frac{(n+2)!}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon}
\frac{1}{z^{n+3}}
(\exp(z)-1)^n \; dz.$$

This is
$$(n+2)! [z^{n+2}] (\exp(z)-1)^n.$$

Observe that $\exp(z)-1$ starts with $z + \frac{1}{2} z^2 + \frac{1}{6} z^3 +\cdots.$

There  are two possibilities here depending on which term from the series expansion is included in the product of the $n$ terms, the  first is  a single  term with $z^3$ and the rest being $z$ which yields
$${n\choose 1} 1^{n-1} \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6} n.$$

The other possibility is two terms in $z^2$ with the rest being $z$
which yields
$${n\choose 2} 1^{n-2} \frac{1}{2^2} = \frac{1}{8} n (n-1).$$

Adding these we obtain
$$\frac{n(3n+1)}{24}$$

for a final answer of
$$(n+2)! \frac{n(3n+1)}{24}.$$

Answer (score 6):

**Note:** This is more a hint than a complete answer providing just some additional information.

> If we exchange the order of summation $k \rightarrow  n-k$ in the LHS of OP's identity we obtain
>
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{2}{(n+2)!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}k^{n+2}
> \end{align*}

Note that the *[Stirling Numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)* $\begin{Bmatrix}m\\n\end{Bmatrix}$ are defined as
\begin{align*}
\begin{Bmatrix}m\\n\end{Bmatrix}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}k^{m}
\end{align*}

> Setting $m=n+2$ we can write OP's expression as
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{2}{(n+2)!}\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}{k}k^{n+2}=\frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}\tag{1}
> \begin{Bmatrix}n+2\\n\end{Bmatrix}
> \end{align*}
>
> So, we essentially have to calculate the Stirling number of the second kind $\begin{Bmatrix}n+2\\n\end{Bmatrix}$ in order to prove OP's claim.

These numbers fulfil a lot of nice relations and we could try to prove the claim e.g. using the *recurrence relation* 
\begin{align*}
\begin{Bmatrix}m\\n\end{Bmatrix}=n\begin{Bmatrix}m-1\\n\end{Bmatrix}+\begin{Bmatrix}m-1\\n-1\end{Bmatrix}\tag{2}
\end{align*}

Since $\begin{Bmatrix}m\\n\end{Bmatrix}$ denotes the number of partitioning a set of $m$ elements into $n$ non-empty blocks, the recurrence relation tells us that we can select the $m$-th element and put it into a block by its own or we have $n$ possibilities to put it into one of $n$ already existing blocks.

But this is a little bit cumbersome and we have already answers with nice solutions. So, one additional remark instead. There are different generalisations of the Stirling Numbers of the second kind and one of them are the so-called *[r-associated Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Associated_Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)*, which are denoted as $$\begin{Bmatrix}m\\n\end{Bmatrix}_r$$

They give the number of $n$ different blocks of $m$ elements, each containing at least $r$ elements.

> We find in Comtet's classic *[Advanced Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9027703809)* in the chapter about Stirling Numbers following relationship of $2$-associated Stirling numbers of the second kind with the Stirling numbers of the second kind 
>   \begin{align*}
> \begin{Bmatrix}n+a\\n\end{Bmatrix}=\sum_{k=a+1}^{2a}\binom{n+a}{k}\begin{Bmatrix}k\\k-a\end{Bmatrix}_2
> \end{align*}
>   Using this relationship together with given table values in this chapter, we can write OP's expression as
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}&\begin{Bmatrix}n+2\\n\end{Bmatrix}\\
> &=\frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left[\binom{n+2}{3}\begin{Bmatrix}3\\1\end{Bmatrix}_2
> +\binom{n+2}{4}\begin{Bmatrix}4\\2\end{Bmatrix}_2\right]\\
> &=\frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}\left[\binom{n+2}{3}
> +3\binom{n+2}{4}\right]\\
> &=\frac{n(3n+1)}{12}
> \end{align*}
>   and the claim follows.

Comment: Interesting work. (+1). Let me point out that I have those ordinary Stirling numbers in the last integral that I obtained, using the bivariate GF $G(z, u) = \exp(u(\exp(z)-1)).$

Comment: E@MarkoRiedel: Thanks, Marko ... and yes, I am aware of it. In fact, I think that with respect to your approach you could *hardly avoid* to use the GF of the Stirling Numbers. :-) Nevertheless I think that explicitly pointing to the Stirling numbers could help OP to get useful associations. (+1)